# USB usage restrictions

Tags: usb, legal, licensing

I find it quite hard to find any information on how to deal with legal issues concerning the use of USB online. I mainly have two question I cannot seem to find a definitive answer to.

1. Is it required by law (US or any other country) to have a VID/PID combination that is registered with the USB-IF? If no, why would you still want to register one?
2. Is the trident logo free for usage without a Logo License Agreement (this logo does not appear in the logo usage guidelines)?

I tried to search myself using these sources but they offer no definitive answer:

- https://www.usb.org/compliance
- https://www.usb.org/logo-license
- https://www.usb.org/sites/default/files/usb-if_logo_usage_guidelines_final_103019.pdf
- https://www.eevblog.com/forum/projects/how-to-label-a-usb-port-(legal)/
- https://www.quora.com/Who-designed-the-USB-symbol-Whats-the-story-behind-the-individual-or-group-who-designed-it-and-the-design-process-they-pursued

Comment: Vendor IDs cost money: https://www.usb.org/getting-vendor-id. A product ID is unique to a vendor and they can assign an appropriate value.

Comment: http://pid.codes/ : an open source "vendor" will issue you a PID from their VID allocation.

Comment: Data point: USB.ORG are rabid enforcers of their "rights".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it required by law (US or any other country) to have a VID/PID combination that is registered with the USB-IF?

It is required by the license agreement, which is a kind of contract. It becomes a matter of law only in the sense that most countries have laws that cover contracts.

> If no, why would you still want to register one?

Because you want your device to be recognized as being distinct from all of the other devices that are already out there. And all of the other device manufacturers want that, too.

> Is the trident logo free for usage without a Logo License Agreement (this logo does not appear in the logo usage guidelines)?

No. If you put the logo on a non-compliant device, this will cause harm to the USB community at large. They will come after you in order to protect themselves.

Comment: Legally, you can do whatever you want as long as you don't say "USB" or use the logo.  Whether that's a good idea or not depends on your goals.

Comment: See also: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/323257/is-a-valid-usb-vid-pid-necessary-for-strictly-embedded-use-of-the-bus

Answer (score 0):

I find the accepted answer misleading, the simple trident logo is not trademarked, neither is the word "USB", see also this topic:
https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/606731/357608